# Postgresql inet find duplicate / overlapping network entries

Tags: sql, postgresql, inet

I've got the following table structure for storing IPs (PostgreSQL 11.14):

```
CREATE TABLE ips (
  ip INET 
);

INSERT INTO ips VALUES ('10.0.0.4');
INSERT INTO ips VALUES ('10.0.0.0/24');
INSERT INTO ips VALUES ('10.1.0.0/23');
INSERT INTO ips VALUES ('10.1.0.0/27');
```

I need to know which network range is duplicate to find overlapping network entries.

Comment: You should define what an overlapping network is.

Comment: What exactly is the output you are looking for? An EXISTS condition using the `<<` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html)  or maybe a left join with it could be a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect already existing overlaps, you can use [`inet <<= inet → boolean`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html#CIDR-INET-OPERATORS-TABLE), similarly to what [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74177119/postgresql-inet-find-duplicate-overlapping-network-entries#comment130965267_74177119): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/E9UsfY2F)

```sql
CREATE TABLE ips (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ip INET        );

INSERT INTO ips (ip) 
VALUES  ('10.0.0.4'),
        ('10.0.0.0/24'),
        ('10.1.0.0/23'),
        ('10.1.0.0/27');
CREATE INDEX ON ips USING gist(ip inet_ops,id);

SELECT 
  a.id AS id1, 
  a.ip AS ip1,
  b.id AS id2,
  b.ip AS ip2 
FROM         ips AS a 
  INNER JOIN ips AS b 
    ON a.ip <<= b.ip 
    AND a.id<>b.id;
```

| id1 | ip1 | id2 | ip2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.0.0.4 | 2 | 10.0.0.0/24 |
| 4 | 10.1.0.0/27 | 3 | 10.1.0.0/23 |

---

If you wish to prevent overlaps from being inserted, you can us a commutative [`inet && inet → boolean` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html#CIDR-INET-OPERATORS-TABLE) in [an exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) on that table: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RWHQq1E0)

```sql
CREATE TABLE ips (
  ip INET,
  CONSTRAINT no_ip_overlaps EXCLUDE USING gist (ip inet_ops WITH &&));

INSERT INTO ips (ip) 
VALUES ('10.0.0.4'),
       ('10.1.0.0/27');
-- You can let the unhandled conflict throw an error
INSERT INTO ips (ip) VALUES ('10.0.0.0/24');
```

> ```
> ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "no_ip_overlaps"
> DETAIL:  Key (ip)=(10.0.0.0/24) conflicts with existing key (ip)=(10.0.0.4).
> ```

You can decide to handle the conflicts as they come, either by ignoring them or being selective:

```sql
INSERT INTO ips (ip) VALUES ('10.0.0.0/24')
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT no_ip_overlaps DO NOTHING;
```

You might one day decide to keep the bigger network in the overlapping pair but right now, only `do nothing` is supported for conflicts on exclusion constraints:

```sql
INSERT INTO ips (ip) VALUES ('10.1.0.0/23') 
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT no_ip_overlaps DO UPDATE 
    SET ip=CASE WHEN ips.ip<<excluded.ip THEN excluded.ip ELSE ips.ip END;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE not supported with exclusion constraints
> ```

Until that day you can revert to a `MERGE` in place of your `INSERT`:

```sql
MERGE INTO ips AS present
USING (SELECT '10.1.0.0/23'::inet AS ip) AS incoming 
  ON (present.ip << incoming.ip)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
  SET ip=incoming.ip
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (ip)
  VALUES (incoming.ip);
```

Since [`MERGE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html) has only [recently been added to PostgreSQL 15](https://www.postgresql.org/about/featurematrix/#sql), on earlier versions you can get away with a [PL/pgSQL upsert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE).

Comment: The search is what I need and there the solution is working. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `SUBSTRING()` here along with a regex pattern:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(ip::text FROM '[^/]+')) cnt
    FROM ips
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Comment: This is only working to find duplicate entries like```'10.0.0.4' and '10.0.0.4/24' but not with '10.0.0.5' and '10.0.0.0/24'

Comment: [masklen ( inet ) → integer](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html#CIDR-INET-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) Returns the netmask length in bits. `masklen(inet '192.168.1.5/24') → 24`. No need to go manual with `::text`.